# Approximation of a given function by rational functions

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, approximation-theory

Given a function $1/\sqrt{x^2−k^2}$ where k is a constant with a small imaginary part, how do you go about constructing a rational approximation? I am interested in the $L_p (p=2 \ or\  ∞)$ norm of the difference being small on the real line. Both the theoretical and the practical implementation is of interest.

Comment: Also posted twice on MathOverflow : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145286/rational-approximation

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/144033/approximation-of-a-given-function-by-rational-functions